# When calling paypal rest api it says invalid scope

Tags: spring-boot, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

[image]Currently when i call below api it says invalid scope
[https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/connect/?scope=openid%20email&response_type=code&redirect_uri={uri}&client_id={clientId}](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/connect/?scope=openid%20email&response_type=code&redirect_uri=%7Buri%7D&client_id=%7BclientId%7D)

can someone help me for this issue, as i need to call below APIs. so, how can i get relevant scopes

- get merchant details : /retail/merchant/v1/status
- create orders : v2/checkout/orders
- capture orders : v2/checkout/orders/+orderId+/capture
- get user info with details : v1/identity/oauth2/userinfo?schema=paypalv1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordinary usage of the REST API does not involve any of that -- [here is the documentation for getting an access token](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/#link-getanaccesstoken).

---

Are you integrating Log in with PayPal, specifically? The URL in your screenshot is specifically for Log in / Connect with PayPal. To request the 'email' scope with such an integration you must enable it within the [Sandbox App Settings](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications). Changes may take 9 hours to have an effect.

[image]

Again, using the REST API has nothing to do with those scope attributes.

Comment: There is no posible to act like shopify, a third party ecommerce to let the store owner configure his paypal account using oauth and let my application call the create order and capture order for the store owner ?

Comment: You may be looking for seller onboarding https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/seller-onboarding/before-payment/ -- though, log in with paypal can be used for some similar purposes. Both of these are distinct to doing your own first-party REST API calls.